# How to get multiple clipboards

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, shortcut-keys, clipboard-manager

I have been using Ubuntu for some time, but still haven't found what would be the most useful thing for me, a way of having multiple clipboards. So is there any software out there at all, or a built-in feature that would make it so that I could use different keyboard shortcuts to copy/cut/paste from and to different clipboards on my machine? So I could be able to do something like this to copy to multiple clipboards (and do very similar things to paste from them and also cut to them):

- Clipboard 1: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- Clipboard 2: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- Clipboard 3: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- Clipboard 4: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

And so on...

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour:    Gnome
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

Comment: Your hand will start to hurt if you CTRL+C+F? too much... Oh, and I think that CTRL+C already triggers when you press the keys, so how to distinguish if you later press F1 as well or not? I think that might become a problem...

Comment: @ByteCommander: That was just an example, but I've changed it now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could also take a look to [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) on [GitHub](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/), it can manage (among lot of things) multiple clipboard organized through tabs.

[image: CopyQ Screenshot]

> CopyQ monitors system clipboard and saves its content in customized tabs. Saved clipboard can be later copied and pasted directly into any application.
>
> Items can be:
>
> - edited with internal editor or with preferred text editor,
> - moved to other tabs,
> - drag'n'dropped to applications,
> - marked with tag or a note,
> - passed to or changed by custom commands,
> - or simply removed.

Less straightforward to install than the accepted answer, but really really powerful and customizable. I fell in love with it :)

Comment: Installing CopyQ is pretty straightforward on Ubuntu. There's a package on 18.04, and a PPA for everything below. And yes, CopyQ rocks!

Answer (score 13):

You could use `gnome-shell-extensions-gpaste`, available in the Universe Repository.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-gpaste
```

But there is no shortcut to get a concrete entry from the history. You have to mark the entry manually if you need another one then the last.

So it's only half an answer.

An idea is, to simulate the behavior (In my case I had to change the entry <kbd>Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd> > <kbd>Delete the active item from history</kbd> from `<Ctrl><Alt>V` to `<Ctrl><Alt>X`)

- Select your first text to copy
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Select the second text to copy
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- …
- Paste the latest text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to delete the entry from the history list
- Paste the latest text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- …

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can I enable this on startup. And keep on everyime

Answer (score 1):

The following is similar to unlimited clipboard in Emacs.

- Install this gnome [shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/)
- copy some text into clipboard
- Shortcuts to toggle selection of copied item:

  - previous copy: Ctrl+F11
  - Next copy: Ctrl+F12
- Ctrl+V (or) Shift-Ins